# Which window to choose?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm making an astronomy observation record application through Python 2.7.5 (using Tkinter). And I want it to have multiple screens. I'm thinking logic like this:

```
 if object is clicked:
   #Go to this screen

 elif this_object is clicked:
   #Go to that screen
```

And stuff like that. My question is, how would I create the different screens and then switch them? I am using the Notebook feature now in Tkinter , but is there a different way to do this? In essence, I want a main screen that can transform into different screens.

I just passed my programming course in Python, and we didn't do this type of multiwindow programming. So please be patient, I can ask many questions :)

EDIT: I tried a simple destroy frame program.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry('200x200')
root.title("This is a test")
frame1 = Frame(root).grid()

def window_closing():
    root.destroy()

destroy_button = Button(frame1, text='Click me!', command = window_closing,
                        width=20, pady=2).grid(row=0, column=0)

mainloop()
```

This destroys the first screen leaving nothing open. I would like to know how I would open another screen from my window_closing function. I expect this to be the main screen. Once a button is clicked, I want the main screen to close and the wanted screen to open. Such as in any simple program.

Comment: do you want multiple windows open or do you want to close on before opening another

Comment: I would like it to close one and open another and zmo, I'll look into it, thanks

Comment: @zmo There are many reasons to choose TKinter over PyQT. First and foremost its part of the standard library which means if you have Python you have TKinter, but PyQT can be much more onerous to get setup especially in corporate/locked down environments.

Comment: Not to be pushy, but @ChristianCareaga can you help me now that the thread is reopened? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined a new function and within that function I made a new frame and used the .lift() feature.